# Ошибка: Unable to find suitable version for angular

Tags: angularjs, bower

Может кто-то сталкивался и может помочь?
Сама ошибка:

```
  $ bower install angular-tree-view --save
  bower angular-tree-view#*       cached https://github.com/hxlniada/angular-tree-view.git#2.2.3
  bower angular-tree-view#*     validate 2.2.3 against https://github.com/hxlniada/angular-tree-view.git#*
  bower angular#~1.4.6            cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.10
  bower angular#~1.4.6          validate 1.4.10 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.4.6
  bower angular#^1.4.8            cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.5.5
  bower angular#^1.4.8          validate 1.5.5 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#^1.4.8
  bower angular#1.5.5             cached https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.5.5
  bower angular#1.5.5           validate 1.5.5 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.5.5
  bower                        ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for angular
```

Пробовал добавить в `bower.json` (добавлял разные версии)

```
 "resolutions": {
      "angular": "1.4.8"
  }
```

Мой `bower.json`

```
{
       "name": "new-dir-angular",
       "version": "0.0.0",
       "dependencies": {
       "angular": "^1.4.0",
       "bootstrap": "^3.2.0",
       "angular-animate": "^1.4.0",
       "angular-cookies": "^1.4.0",
       "angular-resource": "^1.4.0",
       "angular-route": "^1.4.0",
       "angular-sanitize": "^1.4.0",
       "angular-touch": "^1.4.0",
       "angular-material-data-table": "^0.10.9"
      },
      "resolutions": {
           "angular": "1.4.8"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
      "angular-mocks": "^1.4.0"
      },
      "appPath": "app",
      "moduleName": "newDirAngularApp",
      "overrides": {
        "bootstrap": {
          "main": [
             "less/bootstrap.less",
             "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
        ]
     }
   }
 }
```

Спасибо, Всем неравнодушным:)

Comment: Похоже, что у вас установлен ангуляр версии 1.5.x, а angular-tree-view требует >=1.4.6 <1.5.0.

Comment: `"resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.4.0-rc.2"
  }` попробуй поставить

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев 1.4.0? Я попробовал, проблема осталась(

Comment: @VladimirGamalian версия 1.5.5. Можете что-то посоветовать?

Comment: @romka.pm ты пробовал именно `1.4.0`? или `1.4.0-rc.2` это разные дистры

Comment: Последний раз репозиторий angular-tree-view на github пять месяцев назад обновлялся. Можно конечно попробовать pull-request сделать, в надежде, что автор обновит под свежий ангуляр. Ну или даунгрейдиться до ангуляра ветки 1.4.x